# Given an event with date and time, how to send an email 2 days before the event?

Tags: php, database, events, scheduling, reminders

Exactly what the title says.

In my database, I have a list of users and a list of events with date and time.

How do I write the script which enables me to automatically (preferrably) send an email to the users list reminding them about the event 2 days earlier?

EDIT: I was thinking of using [this](http://sabirul-mostofa.blogspot.com/2011/03/wordpress-cron-explained.html)
but I'm not sure how to implement it exactly.

Comment: Have you actually thought about this at all?

Comment: if you're in linux you can use cron , run the script to check if it should send an email

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this a database question?

Depending on your table structure.. something like this might work for you

```
SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN event ON user.id = event.user_id
WHERE DATE(event.event_datetime) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY));
```

This would select all events where the event_datetime is two days from now.

EDIT:

**Here's a quick and dirty, untested script that may work for you**

```
<?php

//change these to whatever your database settings are
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'my_database';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';

//create a new PDO handle
$dbh = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);

//prepare your query
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN event ON user.id = event.user_id
WHERE DATE(event.event_datetime) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))");

//execute query and fetch results
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll();

//iterate through results and send event notification emails
foreach($results as $result) {
    //send event notification emails using your queried results eg. result['email'], $result['event_datetime'], $result['event_info'] ...
}

?>
```

Comment: I need to send an email to the users 2 days BEFORE the event. I updated my answer.

Comment: The query I provided should pull events that will occur two days into the future (the same thing as 2 days before the event)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain what these lines of code do? `//prepare your query
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN event ON user.id = event.user_id
WHERE DATE(event.event_datetime) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))");` and `//prepare your query
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN event ON user.id = event.user_id
WHERE DATE(event.event_datetime) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))");

//execute query and fetch results
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll();` And I take it the the foreach loop sends the actual emails?

Comment: The SQL query will only work if you actually have those tables, I assumed you did since you said `In my database, I have a list of users and a list of events with date and time.` , you will need to modify it to match your table structure, this is just an example. each line of code is commented with an explanation, not sure how else to describe what the code does

Comment: Yes. Thanks. How does this work though? Does this script need a trigger in order to run? Because I might need it to be automatic.

Comment: If you need it to be automatic, you can set up a cron job for it, the cron job should probably look like this: `* */4 * * * php -f /path/to/send_event_emails.php`, that should run that script once every 4 hours. You can access the crontab with the command `crontab -e`, then just paste in the cron job and you're good to go